# Codeigniter error 500 when attempting to load lang file

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I've installed Lubuntu 11.10 x86 on my home server. I previously had Win XP. The server runs well. Apache, PHP and MySQL work great except when it comes to CodeIgniter and language files. First of all php works, I've tested with non CI projects and it's fine. I've also tested a brand new CI project and I get the welcome page. I have a couple projects in CI that have 2 languages and those don't work. To isolate the problem I've copied over the home controller, view and language file. Error 500 when viewing it. If I comment out $this->lang->load('home'); it works fine. If I comment out the content of home_lang.php it works.

I've narrowed it down to the anchor helper in the language file: $lang['home.project1.image'] = anchor('portfolio', 'test'); The url helper is loaded. This worked before. Can I have anchors in the language file? How come this is causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at CodeIgniter's [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) for their Language class, they provide an overview:

> The Language Class provides functions to retrieve language files and
>   **lines of text** for purposes of internationalization.

I'm not sure what's causing your server to flip out, but I'd use the language class to load text strings and wrap any links around them in your view rather than in the _lang file.

Comment: I don't understand because this works fine on my production server on hostgator. Maybe I forgot to set up something on my apache server.

Comment: The routing of the multilingual addon doesn't seem to be working. Before implementing the multilingual addon it worked. Now it doesn't it says [url]/en doesn't exists. Not just on one CI project but all of them.